# chain of angular filters: translation does not refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

In my page code I have expression:

```
{{key | containerkeyname | translate }}
```

where **key** is some string (a field ID), **containerkeyname** filter takes it and outputs translation key (serving human-friendly description for the field), and finally **translate** is translating that key.

This works fine initially (translation is provided), however, when I change translation language, this expression is not re-translated (unlike the rest of the interface that uses a lot of translations, mainly made via directive). I am confused, since translation filter is last in line.

What could be the reason and how I could achieve normal re-translation of this expression?

Comment: This could be because of stateless filters.

Answer (score 0):

AS @Chandermani told, the root cause is likely stateless filter of $translate. (See great feature on the stateful/stateless filters: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/11/19/exploring-angular-1.3-stateful-filters.html) As such, only changing what is before that filter will trigger reaction.

To make it work, I altered the code as follows:

```
 span(translate='{{key|containerkeyname}}')
```